# How can I optimize this duplicates removal query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am working with SQL 2000. I have gotten to a point where I can remove all of the unwanted duplicates based on a complicated set of criteria, but the query now takes hours to complete when it only used to take about 3.5 minutes to get the data with the duplicates included.

For Clarity:
I can have a duplicate rpt.Name field as long as either the rpt.HostName or rpt.SystemSerialNumber fields is also different. Also, I have to determine which entry to keep based on the time stamps of four different columns as some of those columns have missing time stamps.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT 
rpt.[Name],
rpt.LastAgentExecution,
rpt.GroupName,
rpt.PackageName,
rpt.PackageVersion,
rpt.ProcedureName,
rpt.HostName,
rpt.SystemSerialNumber,
rpt.JobCreationTime,
rpt.JobActivationTime,
rpt.[Job Completion Time]
FROM DSM_StandardGroupMembersProcedureActivityViewExt rpt
WHERE
(
  (
      rpt.GroupName = 'Adobe Acrobat 7 Deploy'
   OR rpt.GroupName = 'Adobe Acrobat 8 Deploy'
  )
  AND
  (
      (rpt.PackageName = 'Adobe Acrobat 7' AND rpt.PackageVersion = '-1.0')
   OR (rpt.PackageName = 'Adobe Acrobat 8' AND rpt.PackageVersion = '-3.0')
  )
)
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM   DSM_StandardGroupMembersProcedureActivityViewExt rpt_dupe
  WHERE
  (
    (
     rpt.GroupName = 'Adobe Acrobat 7 Deploy'
      OR rpt.GroupName = 'Adobe Acrobat 8 Deploy'
    )
    AND
    (
     (rpt.PackageName = 'Adobe Acrobat 7' AND rpt.PackageVersion = '-1.0')
      OR (rpt.PackageName = 'Adobe Acrobat 8' AND rpt.PackageVersion = '-3.0')
    )
    AND
    (
      (rpt_dupe.[Name] = rpt.[Name])
      AND
      (
       (rpt_dupe.SystemSerialNumber = rpt.SystemSerialNumber)
    OR (rpt_dupe.HostName = rpt.HostName)
      )
      AND
      (
       (rpt_dupe.LastAgentExecution    < rpt.LastAgentExecution)
    OR (rpt_dupe.JobActivationTime     < rpt.JobActivationTime)
    OR (rpt_dupe.JobCreationTime       < rpt.JobCreationTime)
    OR (rpt_dupe.[Job Completion Time] < rpt.[Job Completion Time])
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the actual execution plan (preferably not the estimated one).

Comment: May be a dumb comment, but have you tried using the keyword DISTINCT to remove the duplicates instead of using the NOT EXISTS clause?

Comment: Dan, you are assuming that his definition of duplicate is based on exactly the set of fields that the query returns.  Although a reasonable assumption, this is not necessarily true.

Comment: I can have a duplicate Name field as long as the HostName or SystemSerialNumber is also different. Also, I have to determine which entry to keep based on the time stamps of four different columns as some of those columns have missing time stamps.

Comment: So your SQL is fauilty: you select everything that isnt in the second select, which says: select everything with the same name and (same serial or same host) - which gives you also back same_naem/same_serial/different_host which in turn is not in the first SELECT then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the not exists clause.

One suggests is to rewrite this as a left outer join:

```
 from <big query> left outer join
      <dups query>
      on <all the fields that constitute a match>
 where <dups query>.<some field> is null
```

I've found that not exists and not in often optimize poorly.

Another suggestion is to change this query to a more direct implementation:

```
with t as (
    SELECT rpt.[Name], rpt.LastAgentExecution, rpt.GroupName, rpt.PackageName,
           rpt.PackageVersion, rpt.ProcedureName, rpt.HostName, rpt.SystemSerialNumber, 
            rpt.JobCreationTime, rpt.JobActivationTime, rpt.[Job Completion Time]
    FROM DSM_StandardGroupMembersProcedureActivityViewExt rpt
    WHERE rpt.GroupName in ('Adobe Acrobat 7 Deploy', 'Adobe Acrobat 8 Deploy') AND
          ((rpt.PackageName = 'Adobe Acrobat 7' AND rpt.PackageVersion = '-1.0') OR
           (rpt.PackageName = 'Adobe Acrobat 8' AND rpt.PackageVersion = '-3.0')
          )
 )
 select t.*
 from t join
      (select name, ..., max(id)
       from t
       group by name, ...
      ) tsum
      on t.id = tsum.id
```

That is, summarize the table by the columns that you want distinct.  Choose one of the rows.  Here, I assume there is an "id" field to uniquely identify each row.  You might have to use a combination of fields, such as name and date.  Without an id, this is more challenging.  In more recent versions of SQL server, you can use row_number().

Answer (score 0):

Try along those lines:

```
SELECT t_main.columns
FROM table as t_main
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT name, MAX(lastAgentExecution)..... FROM table GROUP BY name,serialnumber, hostname
)
as t_joinSerial
ON t_main.name=t_joinSerial.name,lastAgentExecution etc.
where (t_main.AdobeStuff and t_joinSerial is NULL)
```

Comment: How would I deal with a situation where MAX(lastAgentExecution) returns two names and then I have to rely on, in order of preference: MAX(JobActivationTime) or MAX(JobCreationtime) or MAX(JobCompletionTime)?

Comment: in the inner select you dont have one specific record - but you have the maxiumum value of each field over the different records. It doesn't work, if you have the highest lastAgent in one record and the highest jobActivation in another. That would get complicated with this approach. Is this a query you have to make often? Is there a chonce to use additional fields in that table to solve it in more than one step? BTW. Do you have an ID field?